# How to solve this weird issue in html table and css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a weird issue regarding my table content

```
.table {
   position:absolute;
   top:12px;
   left:3px;
   width:87px;
   height:74px;
}

.table tr {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.table td {
  text-align:center;
  padding:1px;color:#000000;
  font-size:1em;
  line-height:1.5em; 
  width: 50px;
}

.table td span {
  padding:3px 5px;
  font-size:1em;   
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td><span>example 1</span>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the text inside `span` have a white background, but I don't want the white background extend to only the edge of the texts, so I applied `padding`.

However, some of the texts are inside the background, but some of them are not.

```
for example
some texts are like these...
 -------
|example|
 -------

or 

 --------
| example|
 --------


This is what I want.
 ---------
| example |
 ---------
```

I have give `td, span` and `tr` larger width but it still not working well.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? What doctype do you have in your html?

Comment: I can't but my doctype is <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `display: inline-block;` on your `span` should fix this.

As is pointed out in the comments below, `span` is by default an inline element, but that does not mean that you can't set its `padding`, setting the `padding` works just fine on inline elements. Your problem lies with the fact that you have set your `table` to be `87px` wide, and the `td` to be `50px` wide. Now the text inside your `span` does not fit inside the `td`, and because it is an inline element, it flows on to the next line. Setting `display: inline-block;` forces the text to not flow onto the next line. Another way to fix this is by setting your `table` and your `td` to be wider, so that it can fit more text on one line.

What you were observing with the "missing" `padding` on one or on both sides of your `span`, was not really "missing" `padding`. The `padding` is added at the start, at the end, at the top and at the bottom of the `span`. So in the places where the `padding` was "missing", it was simply not there because you were looking at a `line-break`, not at the end or the start of the `span`. Another way you could have fixed this is by setting `white-space: nowrap;` on the `span`. That's another way to ensure that the text inside a `span` does not wrap onto the next line.

Comment: `<span>` are `inline` elements. `inline-block` allows them to have `height`, `width`, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the span elemnt has `display:inline` by default. `inline` elements can't be sized and always wrap their content. By setting `display: inline-block` on your span you make it behave halfway between `inline` (can be stacked horizontally, etc.) and `block`, i.e., it can be sized. The default for a non-positioned `block` element is to fill horizontally its container and that's why it works.